# Override max-width of a table cell in a table

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML table, and the second cell's width is limited by `max-width: 700px`.

However, there's a case that I'd like to display a large table in this cell, without max-width (or with a larger value). I'd still like to keep the max-width of the second cell in other cases, that use this HTML as a template, so I don't want to change the value of `max-width` in the `td`, or any other values in the `td`.

I tried overriding `max-width` in the table with `max-width: none;  width: 100vw;`, but it doesn't work. See HTML below:

```html
  <table border="1">
      <tr style="align:center">
          <td><h3>Title1</h3></td>
          <td><h3>Title2</h3></td>
          <td><h3>Title3</h3></td>
          <td><h3>Title4</h3></td>
      </tr>
    
    
      <tr style="align:center">
          <td nowrap="nowrap" style="align:center;padding-right: 10px;padding-left: 10px;">Step 1</td>
          <td nowrap="nowrap" style="max-width: 700px;overflow-x: auto;padding-right: 10px;padding-left: 10px;">
              <table border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse; empty-cells: show; max-width: none;  width: 100vw;">
    
                    <tr style="align:center;text-align:center">
    
                            <td><h5>Inner title 1</h5></td>
    
                            <td><h5>Inner title 2</h5></td>
    
                            <td><h5>Inner title 3</h5></td>
    
                            <td><h5>Inner title 4</h5></td>
    
                            <td><h5>Inner title 5</h5></td>
    
                            <td><h5>Inner title 6</h5></td>
    
                            <td><h5>Inner title 7</h5></td>
    
                            <td><h5>Inner title 8</h5></td>
    
                            <td><h5>Inner title 9</h5></td>
    
                            <td><h5>Inner title 10</h5></td>
    
                            <td><h5>Inner title 11</h5></td>
    
                            <td><h5>Inner title 12</h5></td>
    
                            <td><h5>Inner title 13</h5></td>
    
                            <td><h5>Inner title 14</h5></td>
    
                            <td><h5>Inner title 15</h5></td>
    
                            <td><h5>Inner title 16</h5></td>
    
                            <td><h5>Inner title 17</h5></td>
    
                    </tr>
    
        </table>
        <br></td>
          <td nowrap="nowrap" style="align:center;padding-right: 10px;padding-left: 10px;font-weight: bold;"></td>
    
          <td nowrap="nowrap" style="align:center;padding-right: 10px;padding-left: 10px;">0</td>
      </tr>
    
    
    </table>
```

Edit: It also doesn't work with `!important`. See:

```html
   <table border="1">
  <tr style="align:center">
      <td><h3>Title1</h3></td>
      <td><h3>Title2</h3></td>
      <td><h3>Title3</h3></td>
      <td><h3>Title4</h3></td>
  </tr>


  <tr style="align:center">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" style="align:center;padding-right: 10px;padding-left: 10px;">Step 1</td>
      <td nowrap="nowrap" style="max-width: 700px;overflow-x: auto;padding-right: 10px;padding-left: 10px;">
          <table border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse; empty-cells: show; max-width: none !important;  width: 100vw !important;">

                <tr style="align:center;text-align:center">

                        <td><h5>Inner title 1</h5></td>

                        <td><h5>Inner title 2</h5></td>

                        <td><h5>Inner title 3</h5></td>

                        <td><h5>Inner title 4</h5></td>

                        <td><h5>Inner title 5</h5></td>

                        <td><h5>Inner title 6</h5></td>

                        <td><h5>Inner title 7</h5></td>

                        <td><h5>Inner title 8</h5></td>

                        <td><h5>Inner title 9</h5></td>

                        <td><h5>Inner title 10</h5></td>

                        <td><h5>Inner title 11</h5></td>

                        <td><h5>Inner title 12</h5></td>

                        <td><h5>Inner title 13</h5></td>

                        <td><h5>Inner title 14</h5></td>

                        <td><h5>Inner title 15</h5></td>

                        <td><h5>Inner title 16</h5></td>

                        <td><h5>Inner title 17</h5></td>

                </tr>

    </table>
    <br></td>
      <td nowrap="nowrap" style="align:center;padding-right: 10px;padding-left: 10px;font-weight: bold;"></td>

      <td nowrap="nowrap" style="align:center;padding-right: 10px;padding-left: 10px;">0</td>
  </tr>


</table>
```

Comment: I added a code snippet to your question, can you add your CSS to that so we can see what's happening.

Comment: What is it that you are actually trying to achieve? So far it seems not to be actual tabular data and as such a table would be the wrong tool to use in the first place.

Comment: Thanks @NathanielFlick. The CSS is in the HTML code.

Comment: @tacoshy, I'm trying that the table will be wider, so all of the inner titles will be shown at once without scrolling. It should be wider than the value of max-width of the td, without changing the values in the td.

Comment: This is a (rare) case when you will have to use !important in order to override the inline-styling.

Comment: @AHaworth. It also doesn't work with !important. I added it to the question.

Comment: When are you trying to override this rule, exactly? What event will cause the table cell from being `max-width: 700px` or not? A browser size? Something else?

Comment: @AndyHoffman, I'd like that the table's titles + their content will be shown in a wide cell, without having to scroll to the right, or at least scroll less to the right. In the example above, I have to scroll a lot to see all of the titles.

Comment: I can't see anywhere that you are setting the td to have a max-width setting of your own. Is there some CSS somewhere?

Comment: @AHaworth, it's inline in the HTML. It's set to max-width: 700px in the td, and I tried to set it in the table to max-width: none. However, the table cell is still not wider.

Comment: I thought you were trying to get the td to have a wider width so I assumed you had some CSS somewhere which set its width.

Comment: @AHaworth, no, I'm trying to achieve that in the table in the HTML.